# How to install Windows 7 64 bit on a second partition on a GPT style disk?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, 64-bit, gpt

I'm trying to install Windows 7 64 bit on the second partition of my harddrive, but when I select the second partition in the installation process, I'm unable to install onto it because

> Windows cannot be installed to this partition. The selected partition is of the GPT partition style

Is there a way to install it without formatting the whole disk because I still need the system that's installed on the first partition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Windows 7 on a GPT partition if you boot the Windows 7 install CD in EFI/UEFI mode. If you don't have an EFI/UEFI BIOS, then you have to install Windows 7 on an MBR formatted hard disk.

Comment: There's indeed a UEFI option in the boot menu! Thanks. It's working now